# phpmailer and server maillog

Tags: php, phpmailer

for those who use phpmailer, and love it, I have a question about getting server response information, if possible.

The limit I've seen is that I can send an email, but there's no way to get a post-message-sent response from the mail server.  I am running my own mail server, and I usually watch the maillog file to see what comes back.  And there's some interesting responses from places like yahoo, cox, and other mail servers.

Has any one done anything cool to capture such responses, and tie them back to phpmailer events?

The only recourse I can come up with is to log the entries to the maillog into a database, and somehow match the to= and time sent to any emails I send out using phpmailer.  But I find that's not quite accurate.

So, I'm open to any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at message IDs; any bounces should contain the original. You can use custom headers to add another unique identifier, but there's no guarantee you'll get it back in a bounce. Failing that, you need to use [VERP addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) in order to identify bounced messages accurately, and you can set that explicitly via the `Sender` property in PHPMailer.